# "adb: error: failed to get feature set: device unauthorized" while using wsa

Tags: adb, windows-subsystem-for-android

I had a problem while trying to install a apk to wsa and got the following error

Performing Push Install
adb: error: failed to get feature set: device unauthorized.
This adb server's $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is not set
Try 'adb kill-server' if that seems wrong.
Otherwise check for a confirmation dialog on your device.

I tried 'adb kill-server'. That did not work. I did not see any confiormation